# Flowlayout left alignement in collection view

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, flowlayout

I'm currently trying to get a left alignement on my Collection View.
I'm using a FlowLayout because I need the EstimatedSize property that allows me to resize the cell (the labels inside don't always have the same width).
Here's the code :

```
    itemCollectionView.collectionViewLayout .invalidateLayout()

    if let flowLayout = itemCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 35)
        flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 0, 8)
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
```

[Here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOujl.jpg)

I'm trying to set the left inset to 8 but it doesn't work, it centers the element. With multiple elements, it does the same and create horrible gaps betweens cells.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I think you need to change code at flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 35). You has given fixed with 150 for cell.

Comment: You need to have a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout. With default one it will center (on horizontal axsis) iif there is only on item.

Comment: Any clue how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with the TagCellLayout pod : https://github.com/riteshhgupta/TagCellLayout